# How to Create an Ordered Linked List of Cards by Suit and Value

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes

I have an assignment to make a linked list of card nodes ordered by suit and value. The card struct:

```
   struct card {
        int value;
        char suit;
    }
    struct CNode {
        card * card1;
        CNode * CNode->next;
    }
```

Or something like that; there is a card stsruct and a linked list basically (not sure if that is exactly what I have, but what I have is 100% correct so do not comment about my structs). Now for the code to create the list:

```
    void addCard(Player * player1, Card * card1) {
         CNode * ins_node = malloc(sizeof(CNode));
         ins_node->card = card1;
         ins_node->next = NULL;
         if (player1->hand == NULL);
                  player1->hand = ins_node;
                  return;
         else {
             CNode * temp = player1->hand;
             while (temp->next != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(temp->card->suit, ins_node->card->suit) == 0){
                         //if (ins_node->card->value > temp->card->value) {
                              ins_node->next = temp->next;
                              temp->next = ins_node;
                               return;
                         // }
                }
            }
            temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = ins_node;
}
```

Let's pretend that's all formatted nicely. Now, what I cannot figure out is why this fails to do what I need it to. Ive been working on this for hours and can't get any progress. If you can help/modify existing code, I'd really appreciate it. Currently, this will output the cards ordered by suit, but the value screws everything up. Let me know if you see any easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you hit into a infinite loop:

```
             while (temp != NULL) {
              if (strcmp(temp->card->suit, ins_node->card->suit) == 0){
                         if (ins_node->card->value > temp->card->value) {
                           CNode * prev = temp;
                           temp = temp->next;
                           prev->next = ins_node;
                           ins_node->next = temp;
                           return;
                         }
              }
              temp = temp->next;   //move on no matter match or not. 
            }
```

Comment: That;s exactly what was happening. I fixed the infinite loop and modified it a bit and got the suits to all work nicely. However, I cannot get the cards ordered. the original post should be edited to show my recent fix. This outputs all the cards in a given player's hand ordered by suit, but not ordered by value.

Comment: @Eric , in this loop, you only insert when the card has the same suit as the ones the player had. That's something you need to work on: what happen to those cards with different suits and where to insert?

Comment: I have that at the bottom. If the card does not match any suits, it adds to the end. As of now, let's say for a 15 card hand, I have them sorted by suit. So, for example, I have 4 circles, followed by 5 squares, followed by 3 diamonds, followed by 2 triangles. I cannot get each suit ordered by value however. My goal is to have it be descending or ascending value, broken up by suit (suits not a fixed order person to person).when I uncomment out that section, I get everything ordered except the first  node of each suit.

Answer (score 0):

According to

```
   struct card {
        int value;
        char suit;
    }
```

`suit` is just a `char`, and you cannot compare `char`s by using

```
                if (strcmp(temp->card->suit, ins_node->card->suit) == 0){
```

This error could only go unnoticed if you didn't `#include <string.h>`. Or you didn't show the real definition of `struct card`.